# Links controller in MVC N-layer architecture

Tags: c#, mvc

I have a common issue that I face in my applications (because I don't know any better) and I want to improve.

This is my usual structure:

- Project.UI (MVC Project)
- Project.BLL (Class Lib)
- Project.DAL (Class Lib)

**LinksConfigurationController**

```
public class LinksConfigurationController : BaseController
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var config = new LinksConfiguration();
        var result = await config.GetLinksAsync();
        if (result == null) return View(new List<LinksViewModel>());

        var model = result.Select(item => new LinksViewModel
        {
            Id = item.Id,
            LinkEndpoint = new Uri(item.LinkEndpoint),
            LinkName = item.LinkName
        }).ToList();

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

**LinksConfiguration (In Project.BLL)**

```
public class LinksConfiguration
{
    public LinksConfiguration()
    {
        Repo = new LinksConfigurationRepository();
    }

    public LinksConfigurationRepository Repo { get; set; }
    public async Task<IEnumerable<LinksConfigurationDto>> GetLinksAsync()
    {
        var reuslt = await Repo.GetAllAsync();
        var dto = reuslt.Select(r => new LinksConfigurationDto
        {
            LinkEndpoint = r.LinkEndpoint,
            Id = r.Id,
            LinkName = r.LinkName
        }).ToList();

        return dto;
    }
}
```

**LinksConfigurationRepository (In Project.DAL)**

```
public class LinksConfigurationRepository : IRepository<LinksConfiguration>
{
    public LinksConfigurationRepository()
    {
        Db = new NZBDashContext();
    }
    private NZBDashContext Db { get; set; }
    public async Task<IEnumerable<LinksConfiguration>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return await Db.LinksConfiguration.ToListAsync();
    }
// Rest of the implemented members from the interface
}
```

**IRepo**

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : Entity
{
    T Find(int id);
    Task<T> FindAsync(int id);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync();
    T Insert(T entity);
    IEnumerable<T> Insert(IEnumerable<T> entity);
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> InsertAsync(IEnumerable<T> entity);
    Task<T> InsertAsync(T entity);
    int Remove(T entity);
    Task<int> RemoveAsync(T entity);
    Task<int> ModifyAsync(T entity);
    int Modify(T entity);
}
```

As you can see I have fallen into the trap of constant mapping (I could use Automapper or something similar) and it's a pain and time consuming to actually get anything done. I read through this [article](https://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2013/05/12/the-n-layer-myth-and-basic-dependency-injection/) and while it looks like a good approach, I do not like the idea of all the layers referencing and using the same models (The model used in the view could be completely different to what is actually stored in the DB).

How can I sort this out?

Comment: I'm tempted to suggesting using the ViewModel pattern but what do you mean by your "model could be completely different to what is actually stored in the DB"?

Comment: @RobertKaucher So in the link i posted, it talks about having a `models` project. In that it would contain your `ViewModel` but the `ViewModel` would be referenced in the views (correct) but would also be stored in the DB. Each layer would reference the Models. So I like to separate them and have a `EntityModel` and a `ViewModel` etc.

Comment: No, the ViewModel would need a reference to the Model but depending on how you structured it nothing else would outside of your DAL. Your Model is what's mapped to the DB. The ViewModel is a translation layer between the View and the Model. And multiple ViewModels could relate to a single EntityModel giving you the flexibility you are looking for.

Comment: @RobertKaucher So you are suggesting create a project with my models in and keep the ViewModels in the UI? That's one point fixed :) any idea about interacting with the datalayer? Implementing that massive interface for every entity is quite time consuming, plus i've read that I really don't need a repository with EF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure there is a benefit to the "BLL" layer. I see "BLL" in lots of projects, and people always say it's the "Business Logic Layer" yet I don't see any "Business Logic." [Domain Models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_model) are the best place for "Business Logic".

What your "BLL" project does is map between your Domain Model and your View Models. I've found that mapping from Domain Model to View Model is easiest to manage in the constructors for the view models.

I would recommend two view models: `LinkConfigurationList` and `LinkConfigurationDetails`:

```
public class LinkConfigurationList
{
    public IEnumerable<LinkConfigurationModel> Items { get; private set; }

    public LinkConfigurationList(IEnumerable<LinkConfiguration> links)
    {
        Items = from x in links select new LinkConfigurationDetails(x);
    }
}
```

The constructor for `LinkConfigurationList` would take any enumerable list of `LinkConfiguration` objects. A quick one-liner in LINQ turns it into a list of `LinkConfigurationDetails` objects by passing each `LinkConfiguration` object into the constructor for the details object.

```
public class LinkConfigurationDetails
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public Uri EndPoint { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public LinkConfigurationDetails(LinkConfiguration link)
    {
        Id = link.Id;
        EndPoint = new Uri(link.LinkEndPoint);
        Name = link.LinkName;
    }
}
```

The `LinkConfigurationDetails` constructor takes a `LinkConfiguration` object and maps it to its properties.

@JamieR said:

> Also if the mapping is going to be done in the constructor, it would be a pain to send an empty LinkConfigurationList to the view. It would need to be `new LinkConfigurationList(new LinkConfigurationDetails());`

You would need to pass an `IEnumerable<LinkConfigurationDetails>` object, so something like `new LinkConfigurationDetails[0];` would do the trick.

You could expose an empty constructor that does nothing, but create an empty array of LinkConfiguration objects:

```
public LinkConfigurationList()
{
    Items = new LinkConfiguration[0];
}
```

Now your controller becomes cleaner, and you've eliminated the need for a "BLL" layer that: a) Does not implement "business logic" and; b) Just maps your Domain Models to View Models.

```
public class LinksConfigurationController : Controller
{
    private IRepository<LinkConfiguration> repository;

    public LinksConfigurationController(IRepository<LinkConfiguration> repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IEnumerable<LinkConfiguration> links = await repository.GetAllAsync();
        LinkConfigurationList model = new LinkConfigurationList(links);

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Additionally, you now have a "details" object for your controller's "Details" view:

```
public class LinksConfigurationController : Controller
{
    // ...

    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        LinkConfiguration link = repository.Find(id);
        LinkConfigurationDetails model = new LinkConfigurationDetails(link);

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

### Private Setters, Immutability and Read-only Views

You'll also notice that the `LinkConfigurationDetails` and `LinkConfigurationList` classes all have private setters. Since an "Index" view and a "Details" view is read-only on a web page (e.g. you cannot POST those values back to the server without a `<form>`) marking the setters as private makes your view models immutable -- which reflects the immutable nature of a read-only view.

If you need to edit `LinkConfiguration` data, I would recommend creating new view models, say something like `LinkConfigurationForm`. The `LinkConfigurationForm` would have public getters and setters, which reflects the mutable nature of a web page form allowing you to POST values back to the server to modify data in the database.

### When to Separate the "Details" and "Form" Views

@JamieR said:

> Having private setters and creating a new model for a POST is just duplicating work, the new model would 99% of the time look exactly like the LinksConfiguration. It just seems like a bit of a waste of time?

This all depends on how complex the form is. In this narrow case, the LinkConfiguration domain model is pretty simple. Three text fields would probably be all you need, so creating one view model for a form and for all display needs would suffice. This changes when you need to create a drop down list in your form, or you want some fields in the form read only. If you need to show or hide elements on the page based on certain conditions in the view model, separating the display from the form becomes beneficial.

Let's diverge from the code in the post for a moment and explore a more complex object model: Blog posts.

A blog post has a title, body text and is assigned to one category. In the blog post form, you choose a category from a drop down list. First, our `Post` domain model:

```
public class Post
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Nothing special.

Next, let's look at the "Details" view for a blog post:

```
public class PostDetails
{
    public PostDetails(Post post)
    {
        Title = post.Title;
        Body = post.Body;
        Category = post.Category;
    }

    public string Title { get; private set; }
    public string Body { get; private set; }
    public Category Category { get; private set; }
}
```

We need the Title, Body, and Category. The blog post form is a little different. It will have a `CategoryOptions` property which is a list of `SelectListItem` objects:

```
public class PostForm
{
    public PostForm(Post post, IEnumerable<Category> categories)
    {
        Title = post.Title;
        Body = post.Body;
        categoriesOptions = categories
            .Select(new SelectListItem() { Text = cat.Name, Value = cat.Id.ToString() })
            .ToList();

        categoriesOptions.Insert(0, new SelectListItem() { Text = "Select", Value = string.Empty });
    }

    public string Title { get; private set; }
    public string Body { get; private set; }

    private IList<Category> categoriesOptions;
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoryOptions { get { return categoriesOptions; } }
}
```

Still nothing special, but there is a difference in the data required for the "Details" view compared to the "Form" view. The "Details" view just shows the one category the post is assigned to, but the "Form" view needs a list of options to populate a drop down. This is an example of when separating the two view models and introducing some code duplication helps solve some problems. Just to round this out, let's take a look at a sample Razor view for the blog post form:

```
@model PostForm

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create Blog Post"
}

@using(...)
{
    <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Title)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Title)
    </p>

    <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Body)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Body)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Body)
    </p>

    <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Category)
        @Html.DropdownListFor(m => m.Category, Model.CategoryOptions)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Category)
    </p>

    <p>
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </p>
}
```

I'd like to call attention to how cleanly the dropdown list for the category options is built now:

```
@Html.DropdownListFor(m => m.Category, Model.CategoryOptions)
```

It's just a quick one-liner. No need for "helper" classes. All of the data required for the view is encapsulated by the view model.

Comment: Having private setters and creating a new model for a `POST` is just duplicating work, the new model would 99% of the time look exactly like the `LinksConfiguration`. It just seems like a bit of a waste of time? Also if the mapping is going to be done in the constructor, it would be a pain to send an empty `LinkConfigurationList` to the view. It would need to be `new LinkConfigurationList(new LinkConfigurationDetails());`

Comment: @JamieR: I've updated my answer to address your questions.

Answer (score 3):

**Do you need it?**

From your question it seems that you don't and your [Data Access Layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer) simply forward calls to underlying layer/framework and map properties back/forward.

Complexity (paired with *flexibility*) comes at a cost (as you see) and for unneeded complexity you pay this cost without any benefit. **Drop unneeded complexity**! EF abstracts many underlying DB access details and you may won't need to reintroduce Repository pattern. See also [Implementing the Repository and Unit of Work Patterns in an ASP.NET MVC Application](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) (read more for further details about when - IMO - Repository pattern is needed).

In a different context this kind of refactoring has even a name: **Remove Middle Man**. When a class (or an entire layer, in your case) is doing nothing but delegation/direct mapping then you should remove it entirely.

You'll then have just your presentation DLL and your model DLL (with EF to hide/abstract database access and mapping). You may want to introduce another level of abstraction in your presentation layer ([View Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_model)) when underlying model is too different from model you present to your users (or when interaction model is very complex) but there you should follow common pattern/practice of your UI framework ([MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), [MVP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter), [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel), *MVCVM* or whatever else).

If, in your scenario, you [start designing model layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) then a [code-first](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/what-is-code-first.aspx) approach will let you design your domain classes adding little or nothing code for mapping (no [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) is perfect). With this path (requisites, domain model, presentation) I usually add View Model classes to fit presentation needing otherwise using Model classes directly).

**Repository Pattern, When?**

I'd add a 3rd layer for Data Access only for these (not exhaustive list of) scenarios:

- I need to map deeply different storage methods: relational database, XML file(s), file-system, [NoSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) database.
- I have to switch between different technologies: Entity Framework, [LINQ to SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx), NHibernate.

For simpler scenarios (such as adding a [Service layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_layer)) [mediator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern), [proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) and similars will (usually) do the job.

**Note About Testing**

With an ORM you (usually) have harder time to write tests because it's directly connected to underlying database. In this case to test *extreme* error conditions and/or to simulate network issues/speed can be harder. If you can't automate these tests elsewhere (for example with dedicated system tests instead of unit testing) you may want to introduce a different `DbContext` base class to be used for testing however details depends on ORM you're using, designing approach you selected and specific tests you need to perform.